# width and widthStep different for a binary image in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I load a binary image in OpenCV using cvLoadImage as follows:

```
IplImage* myImg=cvLoadImage(<ImagePath> ,-1); //-1 so that it is read as it is.
```

When I check **myImg->width** and **myImg->widthStep**, I was surprised to find that both of them have slightly different values. Then I went back to look at other images in the dataset, and found that for most cases, the two values were equal, however for some sizeable number of images, the two differed by a value of 1 or 2 mostly.

I though that only for colored images when the number of channels are more than 1, the two values are different, otherwise they are same. Am I wrong? Has anyone noticed this strange behavior before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently if the width is not a multiple of 4 it gets padded up to a multiple of 4, for performance and alignment reasons. So if width is e.g. 255 then widthStep would be 256.

Comment: Is there a correspondence of widthStep(C-api) in C++ api ?

Answer (score 3):

The widthstep of an image can be computed as follow :

```
IplImage *img = cvCreateImage( cvSize(318, 200), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

int width = img->width;
int nchannels = img->nChannels;

int widthstep = ((width*sizeof(unsigned char)*nchannels)%4!=0)?((((width*sizeof(unsigned char)*nchannels)/4)*4) + 4):(width*sizeof(unsigned char)*nchannels);
```

Answer (score 2):

The next pseudocode is a small snippet based on @Nizar FAKHFAKH's answer. It's basically the same thing, but a little clearer (at least for me, jeje). Here it goes:

```
        int size_row_raw = width * n_channels;
        int rem = size_row_raw % 4;
        int width_step = (rem == 0) ? size_row_raw : size_row_raw + rem;
```

Here i assume that size(unsigned char) = 1, which i think is true for c# because sizeof(byte)=1. If we'd like to add this variable to the previous pseudocode, then the change is simple, just change the first line to something like:

int size_row_raw = width * sizeof(datatype_of_interest) * n_channels;

Comment: please refrain from answering outdated questions from 2011. the c-api is no more alive, this is a dead topic. you will be only misleading noobs into thinking, that this would be still a valid option, and trigger an endless cascade of more questions / answers.

Comment: I appreciate the remark @berak. As you can see i'm new at this. I just thought it could be helpful for people who is still forced to use the old c-api (like me). Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I believe the third line could be simplified to a mere:
`int width_step = size_row_raw + rem;`

Comment: @LeonardoConstantino you are absolutely right. Thanks for the improvement on the answer.